# text-overflow ellipsis hides all text in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, ellipsis

I have this collection of items and if the text is too long, I'm expecting it to be trimmed with `...`, not replaced entirely. This problem appears in Firefox. All required css items are there

```
overflow: hidden

white-space: nowrap

max-witdh: 400px
```

What am I missing?

Here is the issue:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group disabled" data-bind="css:{'disabled': !$root.item.Used()}">
   <label>
     <input class="form-control" data-bind="enable: $root.item.Used, checked: Used, attr: { 'data-option': Value }" disabled="" data-option="Letter tab,Legal 9x11,Tab (Indent: 2.50 mm),Cyclic (5),163 g/m2,Plain,White" type="checkbox">
     <span class="control-label" data-bind="text: Value()!=''? Value() : Name()">Letter tab,Legal 9x11,Tab (Indent: 2.50 mm),Cyclic (5),163 g/m2,Plain,White</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Computed CSS:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably a working code will help us better. But trying to recreate your html/css it seems to working on chrome and FF.

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox">
     <span>Letter tab,Legal 9x11,Tab (Indent: 2.50 mm),Cyclic (5),163 g/m2,Plain,White</span>
   </label>
   <br/>
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox">
     <span>Letter tab,Legal 9x11,Tab (Indent: 2.50 mm),Cyclic (5),163 g/m2,Plain,White</span>
   </label>
   <br/>
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox">
     <span>Letter tab,Legal 9x11,Tab (Indent: 2.50 mm),Cyclic (5),163 g/m2,Plain,White</span>
   </label>
   <br/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 100px;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3y0wnxuo/3/

Comment: You're right... I think it might be related with the CSS on the input, because when removing the input in the browser, it works fine.